# Disabling same origin policy for Chrome for local domains

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I'm trying to do cross origin requests on a local *.dev style domain on my Mac OS 10.10 machine using Chrome 45.0.2454.85 (64-bit) for an extension I am developing.

I can't get a message through to `testbox.dev` because every time I do the following code I get value `0` for `status` and `responseText` is always empty. Inspecting the view for the background page shows the console error `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` when those connections are attempted.

I tried closing all instances of Chrome and then relaunching using command `open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security` but still not working.

I tried the `CORS` Chrome extension so I could at least test on local server, but that didn't work.

Tried prefixing my live `api.example.com` URL with `https://www.corsproxy.com/` but the request never completes.

Tried using `cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com` prefix but I get back the error `origin header required`. To fix that I tried sending the origin header using `xhr.setRequestHeader('Origin', http + '//' + window.location.host);` but Chrome does not allow me to proceed with error `Refused to set unsafe header "Origin"`.

I tried adding the following response to my server's Laravel controller method, but did not help:

```
return Response::json($stock, 200, ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*']);
```

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "__MSG_appName__",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "__MSG_appDescription__",
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/icon-16.png",
        "48": "images/icon-48.png",
        "128": "images/icon-128.png"
    },
    "default_locale": "en",
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            //"scripts/chromereload.js"
            "scripts/background.js"
        ],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "images/icon-16.png",
            "32": "images/icon-32.png",
            "38": "images/icon-38.png",
            "48": "images/icon-48.png",
            "64": "images/icon-64.png",
            "128": "images/icon-128.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Workflow Enhancer"
    },
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "http://www.example.com/*",
                "https://www.example.com/*",
                "https://*.freshbooks.com/*",
                "https://*.highrisehq.com/*"
            ],
            "css": [
                "styles/content.css"
            ],
            "js": [
                "scripts/jquery.min.js",
                "scripts/xhrproxy.js",
                "scripts/content.js"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_end",
            "all_frames": false
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "<all_urls>",
        "http://*.dev/*",
        "https://*.dev/*",
        "http://testbox.dev/*",
        "https://testbox.dev/*",
        "http://*.example.com/*",
        "https://*.example.com/*"
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "*"
    ]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    if (port.name != 'XHRProxy_')
        return;

    port.onMessage.addListener(function(xhrOptions) {
        var http = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open(xhrOptions.method || "GET", http + xhrOptions.url, true);
        //xhr.setRequestHeader('Origin', http + '//' + window.location.host);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XHRProxy');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-API-key', 'JSFLIESLIFDFDHSLFEHSLFHSFH');

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                port.postMessage({
                    status : this.status,
                    data   : this.responseText,
                    xhr    : this
                });
            }
        };

        xhr.send();
    });
});
```

xhrproxy.js

```
var proxyXHR = {};

proxyXHR.get = function (url) {
    var port     = chrome.extension.connect({ name: 'XHRProxy_' });
    var settings = {
        method : 'GET',
        url    : url
    };
    var onSuccess;
    var onFailure;
    var self = {
        onSuccess: function (callback) {
            onSuccess = callback;
            return self;
        },
        onFailure: function (callback) {
            onFailure = callback;
            return self;
        }
    };
    port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
        if (msg.status === 200 && typeof onSuccess === 'function') {
            onSuccess(msg.data, msg.xhr);
        } else if (typeof onFailure === 'function') {
            onFailure(msg.data, msg.xhr);
        }
    });
    port.postMessage(settings);
    return self;
};
```

content.js

```
// Localhost test domain.
proxyXHR.get('testbox.dev/api/XYZ/quantity')
            .onSuccess(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .onFailure(function (data, xhr) {
                console.log("HTTP Error while retrieving data.", data, xhr.status);
            });

// Production server domain....produces same error as local domain test above.
proxyXHR.get('api.example.com/api/XYZ/quantity')
            .onSuccess(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .onFailure(function (data, xhr) {
                console.log("HTTP Error while retrieving data.", data, xhr.status);
            });
```

If I change the URL from `testbox.dev` to my production URL `api.example.com` I still get the same cross origin denial.

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: What's your extension manifest? Did you add your local domain to the `permissions` section?

Comment: Please post your manifest file.

Comment: @rsanchez yes, I added it to permissions. Manifest file added to post.

Comment: Also added rest of the code used to make the request.

Comment: If it is just you, you can install a CORS toolbar that fakes it

Comment: I installed and turned on the CORS extension in Chrome just for testing, but that didn't fix it either. Still denied. Also, this isn't for me. Developing this for a client and right now I am blocked from finishing my work because of this problem.

Comment: `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` is not a Cross Origin error. You are probably having some issue with your `https` connection.

Comment: @rsanchez That is possible. I would use http instead, but there is another another security policy that prevents insecure ajax when the page it is on is https. The `api` subdomain might not have a valid certificate and I doubt my client will want to pay for another. I know my local domain obviously has no valid cert. Any way around that?

Comment: You are making the request from the background page of your extension, not from an https page. There is no policy against making xhr via http if you have the permissions set in your manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` is not a Cross Origin error. You are probably having some issue with your https connection. You can either make sure that you have a proper certificate on your server or switch to http.

Note that the following line:

```
    var http = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
```

Doesn't make much sense in a background page, as the protocol will always be `chrome-extension:`.

Comment: That was it! Always fun to be chasing the wrong bug.